# Edit regex to implement role (one letter at least required)

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex on my C# code and I want to edit it by adding constraint to deny the text if the string does not contains at least 1 letter, whatever the language is.

My regex: `@"^(?!\s+$)[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{Zs}\t'.-]+$"`

Any suggestions please.

Comment: `@"^(?=.*\p{L})(?!\s+$)[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{Zs}\t'.-]+$"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you so much, its work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any Unicode letter can be matched with `\p{L}` (see your own pattern).

To match any chars other than a Unicode letter, in order to "get" to the letter in the string, you may use either `\P{L}*`. If you only have strings with no line breaks, you may simply use `.*` or `.*?`.

**NOTE** that this requirements *also covers* the requirement to have at least one non-whitespace char, so the `(?!\s+$)` lookahead becomes redundant (as all it does is cancelling a match if there are only whitespaces in the string).

To require some pattern to appear later in the string, you can use a lookahead:

```cs
@"^(?=\P{L}*\p{L})[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{Zs}\t'.-]+$"
// ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
@"^(?=.*\p{L})[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{Zs}\t'.-]+$"
// ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3d.*%5cp%7bL%7d%29%5b%5cp%7bL%7d%5cp%7bM%7d%5cp%7bN%7d%5cp%7bZs%7d%5ct%27.-%5d%2b%5cr%3f%24&i=+++++%0d%0a++Some+string%0d%0a1+3+4+6++%0d%0a&o=m).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=\P{L}*\p{L})`  - after zero or more chars other than Unicode letters, there must be one Unicode letter
- `[\p{L}\p{M}\p{N}\p{Zs}\t'.-]+` - one or more letters, diacritics, digits, horizontal whitespaces, `'`, `.` or `-` chars
- `$` - end of string.